# Django HttpResponseRedirect pass variable to template and read it

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I would like to use something similar to render_to_response function in Django but with HttpResponseRedirect.

Here's my *views.py* for `render_to_response`:

```py
def somefunction(request):
    return render_to_response('myTemplate.html',{'error': "error"})
```

*mytemplate.html*

```html
{% if error %}
    do something
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could pass GET variables:

```
/mytemplate?variable1="variable_1"
```

You can also use the [messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/)

```
from django.contrib import messages

def view(request):
  # your code
  messages.error(request, "ERROR")
  HttpResponseRedirect("/mytemplate")
```

or  maybe you can add a [session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/)

```
def view(request):
    request.session['error'] = "ERROR"
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/mytemplate")


def my_template(request):
        if request.session.has_key('error'):
           error = request.session.get('error')
           del request.session['error']
        return render(request, "myTemplate.html", locals())
```